# Flickering effect when hovering title. Title over opacity background

Tags: html, css

Having this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Image hover</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
    .gecoitems {list-style-type: none !important;margin:0 auto !important;width:1200px;}
    .gecoitems .gecoitem {margin-bottom:20px;display:block;}
    .gecoitems .column {float:left;}
    .gecoitems {width:1200px;}
    .gecoitems .gecoitem.normal {width:1200px;height:252px;background:#006505;color:#fff;}

    /* links */
    .gecoitems .gecoitem:hover {opacity:1;}
    .image-listitem-wrapper {position:relative;}
    .image-listitem-wrapper .title {position:absolute;top:40%;left:0;opacity:1.0;color:#ffffff;text-transform: uppercase;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:35px;line-height:normal;}
    .image-listitem-wrapper .title.hover {display:none;color:#000000;top:35%;}
    .image-listitem-wrapper .title.hover .services {text-transform: lowercase;display:block;}

    .gecoitems .gecoitem.wrapper-title.hover:hover {opacity:0.4;}
    .gecoitems .gecoitem.wrapper-title.hover:hover + .title.hover {display:block;}


    .slow-fade {
       opacity: 0.8;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;    
       }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="gecoitems">
            <li>
        <div class="image-listitem-wrapper default-image">
            <a href="#" class="wrapper-title hover slow-fade gecoitem normal"></a>
            <span class="title hover">TITLE<span class="services">Subtitle</span></span>
        </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get almost what I want. When I hover the area I get opacity 0.4 background with a title above, but when I hover the title/subtitle I get a "flickering effect".I dont want this "flickering effect". How do I get rid of that? (I'm quite sure it's this:

`.gecoitems .gecoitem.wrapper-title.hover:hover + .title.hover {display:block;}` that's the issue but how do I solve this? I don't want anything top happen when I hover the title (just want the opacity 0.4 to "stay there")

A JS Fiddle to explain further: https://jsfiddle.net/1rLzeht9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following snippet, I changed some of the `display:block` to `opacity:1`, and added a z-index property to the `.title`

Also I moved your css, got rid of the body, meta etc tags for the purpose of this snippet

```css
.gecoitems {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  width: 1200px;
}
.gecoitems .gecoitem {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}
.gecoitems .column {
  float: left;
}
.gecoitems {
  width: 1200px;
}
.gecoitems .gecoitem.normal {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 252px;
  background: #006505;
  color: #fff;
}
/* links */

.gecoitems .gecoitem:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.image-listitem-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.image-listitem-wrapper .title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1.0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: normal;
  z-index:-1;
}
.image-listitem-wrapper .title.hover {
  opacity: 0;
  color: #000000;
  top: 35%;
}
.image-listitem-wrapper .title.hover .services {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: block;
}
.gecoitems .gecoitem.wrapper-title.hover:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.gecoitems .gecoitem.wrapper-title.hover:hover + .title.hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.title:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.slow-fade {
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="gecoitems">
    <li>
      <div class="image-listitem-wrapper default-image">
        <a href="#" class="wrapper-title hover slow-fade gecoitem normal"></a>
        <span class="title hover">TITLE<span class="services">Subtitle</span></span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

You may also add [`pointer-events:none`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/) to the `.title` element, see [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rLzeht9/1/). This removes the title being the target of mouse events

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great help!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that since `.title.hover` is not inside `.wrapper-title` you lose the :hover selector when the mouse goes over `.title`, therefore the element is hiden, bringing again the hover to the wrapper, and so on.

You can avoid that by setting `pointer-events: none` to the title.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: yeah.. Luckily I don't care about IE, I say nobody should care, but well.. this is the real world..

Comment: Other people do care. If want to have this as a part of serious website. IE has to be considered.

Comment: I know other people care, and that's why we still have some projects where ie 8 should be supported. Anyways, my comment was more directed to "I don't care about old versions". Btw, what version of ie do you think has to be considered?

Comment: I agree. at least ie8+